# Automation error while extracting data from another Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a macro which extracts data from another Excel worksheet in different workbook, the macro will let user choose which workbook and which worksheet users'd like to copy data from, however now I'm getting an error message of

> Automation error

at line of

```
Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AD" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AD" & X))
```

I'm not sure why this causes error, cause **when I use this line for extracting data from the same workbook, it works fine**.

For your reference, the rest of the code is here:

```
Sub CopyFourColumns()
   '// Declare your variables.
    Dim wSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim wSheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim wSlastRow As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim RngToCopy As Range
    Dim RngToPaste As Range
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    '// Set here Workbook(Sheets) names
    With wkbCrntWorkBook
        Set wSheet2 = ActiveSheet
    End With

    'extract data from another excel file
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wSheet1 = ActiveSheet

        '// Here lets Find the last row of data
        wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '// Now Loop through each row
    For X = 2 To wSlastRow

        'insert wSlastRow no of rows to worksheet Summary
        Rows(wSlastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        'Set RngToPaste = wSheet2.Range("P" & (X + 1))
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AD" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AD" & X))
        With wSheet1
            'Set RngToCopy = Union(.Range("P" & X), .Range("P" & X))
            Set RngToCopy = Union(.Range("P" & (X)), .Range("P" & X))
            RngToCopy.Copy RngToPaste
        End With

        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AF" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AF" & X))
        With wSheet1
            Set RngToCopy = Union(.Range("W" & (X)), .Range("W" & X))
            RngToCopy.Copy RngToPaste
        End With

        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AH" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AH" & X))
        With wSheet1
            Set RngToCopy = Union(.Range("C" & (X)), .Range("C" & X))
            RngToCopy.Copy RngToPaste
        End With

        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AI" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AI" & X))
        With wSheet1
            Set RngToCopy = Union(.Range("R" & (X)), .Range("R" & X))
            RngToCopy.Copy RngToPaste
        End With
        'Add Schedule value
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AE" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AE" & X))
            RngToPaste.Value = "Scheduled"
        'Add Emaill address value
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("U" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("U" & X))
            RngToPaste.Value = ".com"
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("V" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("V" & X))
            RngToPaste.Value = ".com"
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AA" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AA" & X))
            RngToPaste.Value = ".com"
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AB" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AB" & X))
            RngToPaste.Value = ".com"
        Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AC" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AC" & X))
            RngToPaste.Value = ".com"
    Next X

        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If
    End With

    '// Simple Msg Box
    MsgBox "Copy & Paste is Done."
End Sub
```

Here's the sample data:
[image]

Comment: What is X when you get the error?

Comment: Why use `Union` at all? `Set RngToPaste = wSheet2.Range("AD" & X)`

Comment: @Rory : +1 . As you are only describing one cell at a time, the `Union` seems pretty useless. Why do use parenthesis on the first `X` and not on the second? There is no need for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use objects with `Set ... = ...` don't forget to free the reference at the end of code with `Set ... = Nothing`.

And you don't have to use objects so much, if it not interesting for you regarding code volume or some other aspects. (Especially for the copy)

Here is your code cleaned and reviewed, give it a try :

```
Sub CopyFourColumns()
'// Declare your variables.
Dim wSheet1 As Worksheet, _
    wSheet2 As Worksheet, _
    wSlastRow As Long, _
    X As Long, _
    wkbSourceBook As Workbook, _
    wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook

Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
'// Set here Workbook(Sheets) names
Set wSheet2 = wkbCrntWorkBook.ActiveSheet

'extract data from another excel file
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        Set wSheet1 = wkbSourceBook.ActiveSheet

        '// Here lets Find the last row of data
        wSlastRow = wSheet1.Rows(wSheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '// Now Loop through each row
        For X = 2 To wSlastRow
            'insert wSlastRow no of rows to worksheet Summary
            wSheet1.Rows(wSlastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            wSheet1.Range("P" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("AD" & X)
            wSheet1.Range("W" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("AF" & X)
            wSheet1.Range("C" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("AH" & X)
            wSheet1.Range("R" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("AI" & X)

            'Add Schedule value
            wSheet2.Range("AE" & X).Value = "Scheduled"

            'Add Emaill address value
            wSheet2.Range("U" & X).Value = ".com"
            wSheet2.Range("V" & X).Value = ".com"
            wSheet2.Range("AA" & X).Value = ".com"
            wSheet2.Range("AB" & X).Value = ".com"
            wSheet2.Range("AC" & X).Value = ".com"
        Next X

        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If
End With

'Free objects
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = Nothing
Set wSheet2 = Nothing
Set wkbSourceBook = Nothing
Set wSheet1 = Nothing

'// Simple Msg Box
MsgBox "Copy & Paste is Done."
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I have tried you code and it works smoothly^^ but do you know how to modify the code so that I could choose which worksheet I want to copy from another target workbook

Comment: Yup, it's pretty easy, just change this line `Set wSheet1 = wkbSourceBook.ActiveSheet` to `Set wSheet1 = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("Sheet's name comes here")` and if you want to be able to select on the fly the sheet, you'll most probably have to do an UserForm. If your issue is solved please validate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I help you improve you code, there is no need to use so much

```
Set RngToPaste = Union(wSheet2.Range("AD" & (X)), wSheet2.Range("AD" & X))
```

Somehow, I just not sure why you calculate the last row value of 4 columns and assign in the same variable?

```
wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Below is the code I enhance from your code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook
Dim CurrentWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim DataWorksheet As Worksheet


Sub CopyFourColumns()
'// Declare your variables.
Set CurrentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set CurrentWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim CurrentRowPointer As Long

'extract data from another excel file
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set DataWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set DataWorksheet = DataWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        '// Here lets Find the last row of data
        'wSlastRow = DataWorksheet.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        'wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        'wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        'wSlastRow = wSheet1.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    '// Now Loop through each row
    For CurrentRowPointer = 2 To DataWorksheet.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        'insert wSlastRow no of rows to worksheet Summary
        DataWorksheet.Rows(DataWorksheet.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        CurrentWorksheet.Range("P" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = DataWorksheet.Range("AD" & CurrentRowPointer).Value
        CurrentWorksheet.Range("W" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = DataWorksheet.Range("AF" & CurrentRowPointer).Value
        CurrentWorksheet.Range("C" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = DataWorksheet.Range("AH" & CurrentRowPointer).Value
        CurrentWorksheet.Range("R" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = DataWorksheet.Range("AI" & CurrentRowPointer).Value

        'Add Schedule value
        DataWorksheet.Range("AE" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = "Scheduled"

        'Add Emaill address value
        DataWorksheet.Range("U" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = ".com"
        DataWorksheet.Range("V" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = ".com"
        DataWorksheet.Range("AA" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = ".com"
        DataWorksheet.Range("AB" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = ".com"
        DataWorksheet.Range("AC" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = ".com"

    Next X

    DataWorkbook.Close False
    End If
End With

'// Simple Msg Box
MsgBox "Copy & Paste is Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: it still shows `Automation error `at line `DataWorksheet.Range("P" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = CurrentWorksheet.Range("AD" & CurrentRowPointer).Value`

Comment: I would like to know what value you are copied from Row AD to Row P of another worksheet? `DataWorksheet.Range("P" & CurrentRowPointer).Value = CurrentWorksheet.Range("AD" & CurrentRowPointer).Value`

Comment: I just added me sample data to my question for your reference.

Comment: I tested the data at my side and it run without error. Maybe you can try to create a new workbook with the macro code and try to execute it? I not sure whether your data source got corrupted or not.

Comment: and it really copies the data? Since it's working at my side as well now, but just not copy anything.

Comment: I am totally confuse with the last comment you mentioned here. Are you telling me that there was no error from macro but the value was not be copied over?